# How to update different component textbox value in React js..?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, reactjs, textbox

**Environment**

- OS : Windows 7 - 64 bit
- Framework : CodeIgniter PHP MVC
- JS: React Js

I am having two different components `LeftComponent` and `RightComponent` which is merged by `MergeLeftRightComponent`.

`MainApp` which is responsible for rendering.

Having textbox in `LeftComponent` and `RightComponent`. While changing value in **left textbox**, i need to update value in **right textbox** and **vice-versa**.

How to achieve this..?

Framed this app from the basics of [codeofaninja](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2016/07/react-crud-tutorial.html) tutorial.

#### My app sample view

[image]

### Codes

view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>React page</title>
</head>
<body>
      <div class='task-container' id='task-container'>
      </div>

<!-- react js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>

<!-- react components -->
<script type="text/babel" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/components/right.component.js');?>"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/components/left.component.js');?>"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/components/merge.component.js');?>"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/components/main.component.js');?>"></script>

<!-- jQuery library required by bootsrap js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

main.component.js

```
    var MainApp = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
      var modeComponent = <MergeLeftRightComponent changeAppMode={this.changeAppMode} />;
      return modeComponent;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<MainApp />,document.getElementById('task-container'));
```

merge.component.js

```
window.MergeLeftRightComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            inputVal:"",
        };
    },
    changeinputVal: function(e) {
      this.setState({
        inputVal: e.target.value,
      });
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
          <div className='task-container'>
            <LeftComponent inputVal={this.state.inputVal} onChange={this.changeinputVal}/>
            <RightComponent inputVal={this.state.inputVal} onChange={this.changeinputVal}/>
          </div>
      );
    }
});
```

left.component.js

```
window.LeftComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      task_name:"Mountain task"
    };
  },
  handleChange: function(e){
    this.setState({
      inputVal:e.target.value
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div className="left-box">
        <div className="info-container">
          <input type="text" className="task-name form-control" value={this.props.task_name} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

right.component.js

```
window.RightComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      task_name:"Mountain task"
    };
  },
  handleChange: function(e){
    this.setState({
      inputVal:e.target.value
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div className="right-box">
        <div className="info-container">
          <input type="text" className="task-name form-control" value={this.props.task_name} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Help me to achieve this.
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

in the `merge.component.js` file you need to bind `changeinputVal` function

In `left.component.js` call `changeinputVal` function at your input function

```
 handleChange: function(e){
   this.setState({
     inputVal:e.target.value
   });
  this.props.onChange(e);
 },
```

`merge.component.js` file

```
      class MergeLeftRightComponent extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.changeinputVal = this.changeinputVal().bind(this);
            }
            getInitialState() {
                return {
                    inputVal: ""
                };
            }
            changeinputVal(e) {
                this.setState({
                    inputVal: e.target.value
                });
            }

            render() {
                return (
                    <div className='task-container'>
                        <LeftComponent inputVal={this.state.inputVal} onChange={this.changeinputVal}/>
                        <RightComponent inputVal={this.state.inputVal} onChange={this.changeinputVal}/>
                    </div>
    );
```

Comment: Can you add the `merge.component.js` file changes...? Then i can understand clearly..

Comment: I got error while using `class MergeLeftRightComponent extends React.Component`. I am using only `window.MergeLeftRightComponent = React.createClass({` type.. And showing error in `constructor(props)`

Comment: Can you say where i am going wrong..? I can't able to use Class type like `class App extends Component {` and aslo `import './App.css';` ... Some of them use `var reactComponent = React.createClass({` , but showing error for me.. please help..